# What is the meaning of the sentence "I'll serve you out" from Dickens' Great Expectations?

Tags: idiom-meaning, charles-dickens, nineteenth-century-english

In Chapter 18, Mr Wopsle is at the Three Jolly Bargemen, giving his audience a theatrical rendition of a murder case as reported in the newspaper:

> The victim faintly moaned, "I'm done for," and the murderer barbarously bellowed, "I'll serve you out."

Is the usage of the phrasal verb "serve out" possibly a reference to the killing of an animal in order to serve it up as a dish in a meal?

Comment: From [lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/synonym/fight_back), *(**archaic**) - serve someone out = **give someone a Roland for an Oliver***. Which last expression wasn't known to me, but apparently it's “to give as good as one gets” (tit for tat). But I'm more familiar with *I'll **see** you out* = *I'll **outlive** you*, which makes ,more sense in the given context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary has this definition under "[serve, v.1.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/176665)," along with the earliest cited usage and a directly comparable usage:

> 49. **to serve out**: to punish, take revenge on; to retaliate on (one) for something objectionable. colloq. (orig. Boxing slang). Also (Hunting slang), to ‘punish’ or smash (a fence).
>
> > 1817   Sporting Mag. 50 18   The butcher was so completely **served out**, that he resigned all pretensions to victory.
> >
> > 1863   C. Kingsley Water-babies v. 183   I will **serve you out** for telling the salmon where I was!

I see no evidence that it refers to killing an animal. The same phrasal verb is used to refer to giving food or drink, with an earlier first cited usage:

> 43. c. to serve out, to distribute or deal out (food, ammunition, etc.) in portions. [...]
>
> > 1793   J. MacDonell Diary 15 Aug. in C. M. Gates Five Fur Traders (1933) 101   Our Bourgeois came up with us and ordered each man a dram, which I **served out** to them.

It may be that this form of service was then generalized to other subjects or objects. In the 1824 collection of anecdotes *[Boxiana](https://books.google.com/books?id=-oUoAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP291&lpg=PP291&dq=%22%09The%20butcher%20was%20so%20completely%20served%20out%22&source=bl&ots=7N74BlEIog&sig=ACfU3U0X8ZmvQKNUmbe1aEq6wsYon8u87Q&hl=en&ppis=_e&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwir86Tz9b_nAhXRnuAKHZ5OB7IQ6AEwAXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=served%20out&f=false)*, these uses appear that emphasize what is being served out or dealt:

> In closing, the *punishment* which Carter **served out** to his opponent was tremendous in the extreme [...] (p. 316)
>
> Much *punishment* was **served out** on both sides [...] (p. 349)

Even without *punishment* being specified, then, the boxing context would convey what is meant in the following metaphor of boxer as a customer of blows:

> However, at all events, Ned (the boxer) is a *customer* not easily to be **served out** (p. 108)

Comment: 'Pay out' is (or was) common as well as 'serve out', to mean 'retaliate'.

Comment: "Dole out" too. "Payback," even. "Mete out." The connection between capital exchanges and violence is interesting.

Comment: To pay out literally means to pay what is owing (in money), so to 'pay someone out' means to exact a calibrated revenge proportional to the original offence.

Comment: Thank you!  It looks like I may have to shell out and subscribe to the OED online! Again, thanks!